# avr:atmega328bb doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATMEGA328BB error in arduino bootloading

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader

I am using arduino uno to bootload atmega-328p . I have done all connections properly as shown in arduino.cc site . But then a warning give arduino ide that

board avr:atmega328bb doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATMEGA328BB

I have changed my ide's preferrence.txt as
build.board = AVR_ATMEGA328BB

After that also the error is showing . I am using arduino ide on windows.
What wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is problem with connection of IC base . Loose connection of atmega328p pins made bootloader to not recognize the board . Thus giving the error . Proper ic connection solved the problem.